# Missing last character

Tags: c

I am reversing a String without using inbuilt function . its reversing every character but missing last character

here is the program

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char str[10],rev[10];
    int i,j,k;

    clrscr();

    printf("enter the string \n");
    scanf("%s",str);

    for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
        k=i-1;

    for(j=0;j<=i-1;j++)
    {
        rev[j]=str[k];
        k--;
    } 
    rev[j]='\0';

    printf("reverse=%s",rev);
    getch();
}
```

I am not getting why the last Char is missing

Comment: what do you put in as input?

Comment: That code is *very* hard to read. Please format it better.

Comment: if i gave input like apollo its printing llopa

Comment: As for your problem, for some example input, what is the actual and expected output?

Comment: What is your first for loop doing?

Comment: This is not C++. The program should not compile and even if it did, it's far from any regular C++ code.

Comment: if i enter apollo actually it should reverse string like ollopa but its answer is llopa the 'o' is missing

Comment: Regarding your calculation of the length of the input string, why not simple set `k` *after* the loop? No use in doing it inside the loop. Incidentally that will also fix your problem. :) (Also, your current way, with assigning `k` inside the loop, will cause [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) for input strings that are empty or contain only a single character.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
k = i;
```

You miscounted it. 
Your expression `k = i-1;` doesn't leave space for the whole reversed string.

Comment: rev[j]='\0'; i am confused about this code why we have to set it to 0?

Comment: That indicates the end of the string, so the compiler knows until when to print. If there was no terminating character it would print forever.

Answer (score 2):

The code that computes the length of the string is missing a semicolon:

The compiler interprets it as

```
for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
    k=i-1;
```

while the intention has probably been to have

```
for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
    ;
k = i - 1;
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/uFcN5Q)

Now that the code is "working", you should fix an error that could cause undefined behavior: limit the length of the input to 9 characters in `scanf`, like this:

```
scanf("%9s", str);
```

Without 9, the user could cause undefined behavior by entering more than nine characters, and overflow your ten-byte buffer.